# Fetching column data from some table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I got these 3 tables

**Ques Table**

```
 Ques |Ans          |QuesID|LangID
__________________________________________
Ques1|Ques1's Answer|1     |1
Ques2|Ques2's Answer|2     |2
```

LangID is a Foreign Key that References LangID in table Languages

**Languages Table**

```
LangID         |Description|LanguageID
______________________________________
1              |French     |1
2              |English    |2
```

Language Table is for website's contents' language

**EditorLanguage table**

```
LanguageID|Value|Desc
______________________
1         |fr-FR|French
2         |en-US|English US
```

EditorLanguage Table is for RadEditor's Language

When a new Ques is added:-

The InsertUpdateQues Stored Procedure inserts the following values in Ques Table:-

QuesID, Ques, Ans, LangID

Now on my Ques Page, I have the following:-

```
-A drop down list box to select language (this drop down is bound to EditorLanguage Table's Desc column)
-A Text Box for Ques
-Telerik RadEditor for Ques's Answer
- Submit cancel buttons
```

Now lets say the langauage selected from the drop down is French whose language ID=1, Value=fr-FR, desc=French

Now how do I pass this LangID value to InsertUpdateQues Stored proceedure. I mean how it should get this value?

I am confused because of this Foreign Key thing..new too ms sql

How will the logic be formed? What is even going on here ? 
so ok it will get LangID somehow but how and what good will that do ? I am suddenly feeling lost.

Comment: My mistake.  I thought you were asking about how to pass the value to the SP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are `Languages` and `EditorLanguage` separate tables?  Based on what you're showing us, it looks like they would be better as a single table.  The table names and key names are unintuitive as well.

As it stands right now, you're going to have to translate the `LanguageID` that the form is posting into a `LangID` that the `Ques` table needs.  This can be done in code by hitting the database (or a cached lookup) to select `LangID` from `Languages` where `LanguageID` equals the value you have.  Or you can do this inside of the stored procedure you're calling (so it's only a single trip to the database) by either selecting the value into a variable and using the variable in your insert/update, or by using a subquery in your insert/update to select the value.

Note that this may get clouded if there's any kind of one-to-many relationship between `Languages` and `EditorLanguage`.